# What are the restrictions on repeat visits to Israel when no tourist visa is required?

Tags: tourist-visas, israel, repeat-visits

Suppose you have a passport of a state from which you can visit Israel as a tourist without first obtaining a visa. AFAIK your tourist visit may last up to 3 months. Now suppose you leave Israel (without overstaying), and want to come back in. I assume you can't just leave for 5 minutes and then come back in for another 3 months, repeatedly, right?

So, my question is: What are the restrictions on repeat entry, and for how long are you thus restricted?

Note: I'm asking both about formal legal restrictions and about what happens in practice (e.g. what border police officers would typically do).

Comment: Do you have reason to think there is a general rule?  For a lot of countries, this is simply handled by the border officer's discretion, case-by-case.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I have no idea whether there actually is a formal rule. But see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Visitors who require a visa for tourism are allowed to visit for up to three months, with the duration of stay decided by the border guards. This appears to be a legal delegation. (Source: [Israel Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Visas.aspx)). There is a mechanism for applying for an extension to your stay.

We can assume that entry of non-visa visitors is similarly controlled.

The general principle applied elsewhere is that a visitor should not be attempting to circumvent the requirements of other visas by making repeated visits. Thus, a number of short visits over a limited period is unlikely to be a problem, but repeated visits of 90 days will quickly be shut down.

All of this is dependent on the exact circumstances and the eloquence of the visitor, which is why it's delegated to the border guards.

If you're looking for a rule of thumb, assume you must leave the country for at least as long as your visit.

Comment: It seems you're basing your answer on a common-sense assumption... do you have some specific information or experience to share?

Comment: Control of entry is delegated to the border guards. It says as much on the page I linked to. No doubt there is some specific guidance given as part of their training but I doubt that it's published. The general principle is what's applied in most countries around the world. The days of cross-border visa runs exploiting loopholes in the regulations are long gone. You might yet find somewhere in the world you can do it, but nowhere that I've been to, visa or no visa.